# Unable to paginate using Infinite Scroll and Flask

Tags: jquery, python, flask, infinite-scroll

I have a Flask app that serves content to users.  I'm trying to use [Infinite-Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) to present automatically paginated content to users as they scroll down, but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

The app paginates once, but then doesn't work as expected for the next time.  It's intended to paginate using a token that gets assigned to a button using a query param.

Instead of getting a third page of content while scrolling I get a message indicating that there's no more content.  This appears to be because the plugin is using an otherwise invalid token that it derived from adding 10 to the previous valid token.  I can't seem to find a setting to modify this behavior and have no idea why it's happening.

I've included a complete, minimal example that demonstrates this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, render_template_string, request, make_response, redirect, session, url_for, abort

application = Flask(__name__)
application.debug=True


@application.route('/posts/', methods=['GET'])
def get_posts():

    token = request.args.get('token', None)

    if token:
        token = int(token)

    if token is None:
        posts = [
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 1},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 2},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 3},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 4},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 5},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 6},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 7},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 8},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 9},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 10},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 12},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 13},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 14},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 15},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 16},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 17},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 18},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 19},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 20},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 21},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 1},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 2},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 3},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 4},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 5},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 6},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 7},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 8},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 9},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 10},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 12},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 13},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 14},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 15},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 16},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 17},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 18},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 19},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 20},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 21}
        ]

    elif token == 21:
        print "Token is 21"
        posts = [
            {"name" : "Josh", "id" : 42},
            {"name" : "Kevin", "id" : 43},
            {"name" : "Larry", "id" : 44},
            {"name" : "Richard", "id" : 45},
            {"name" : "Carl", "id" : 46},
            {"name" : "Leslie", "id" : 47},
            {"name" : "Jordan", "id" : 48},
            {"name" : "Matt", "id" : 49},
            {"name" : "Steve", "id" : 50},
            {"name" : "Isaac", "id" : 51},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 52},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 53},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 54},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 55},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 56},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 57},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 58},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 59},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 60},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 61},
            {"name" : "Josh", "id" : 62},
            {"name" : "Kevin", "id" : 63},
            {"name" : "Larry", "id" : 64},
            {"name" : "Richard", "id" : 65},
            {"name" : "Carl", "id" : 66},
            {"name" : "Leslie", "id" : 67},
            {"name" : "Jordan", "id" : 68},
            {"name" : "Matt", "id" : 69},
            {"name" : "Steve", "id" : 70},
            {"name" : "Isaac", "id" : 71},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 72},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 73},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 74},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 75},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 76},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 77},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 78},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 79},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 80},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 81}
        ]

    elif token == 81:
        print "Token is 81"
        posts = [
            {"name" : "Josh", "id" : 42},
            {"name" : "Kevin", "id" : 43},
            {"name" : "Larry", "id" : 44},
            {"name" : "Richard", "id" : 45},
            {"name" : "Carl", "id" : 46},
            {"name" : "Leslie", "id" : 47},
            {"name" : "Jordan", "id" : 48},
            {"name" : "Matt", "id" : 49},
            {"name" : "Steve", "id" : 50},
            {"name" : "Isaac", "id" : 51},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 52},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 53},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 54},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 55},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 56},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 57},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 58},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 59},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 60},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 61},
            {"name" : "Josh", "id" : 62},
            {"name" : "Kevin", "id" : 63},
            {"name" : "Larry", "id" : 64},
            {"name" : "Richard", "id" : 65},
            {"name" : "Carl", "id" : 66},
            {"name" : "Leslie", "id" : 67},
            {"name" : "Jordan", "id" : 68},
            {"name" : "Matt", "id" : 69},
            {"name" : "Steve", "id" : 70},
            {"name" : "Isaac", "id" : 71},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 72},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 73},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 74},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 75},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 76},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 77},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 78},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 79},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 80},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 101}
        ]

    elif token == 101:
        print "Token is 101"
        posts = [
            {"name" : "Josh", "id" : 42},
            {"name" : "Kevin", "id" : 43},
            {"name" : "Larry", "id" : 44},
            {"name" : "Richard", "id" : 45},
            {"name" : "Carl", "id" : 46},
            {"name" : "Leslie", "id" : 47},
            {"name" : "Jordan", "id" : 48},
            {"name" : "Matt", "id" : 49},
            {"name" : "Steve", "id" : 50},
            {"name" : "Isaac", "id" : 51},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 52},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 53},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 54},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 55},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 56},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 57},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 58},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 59},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 60},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 61},
            {"name" : "Josh", "id" : 62},
            {"name" : "Kevin", "id" : 63},
            {"name" : "Larry", "id" : 64},
            {"name" : "Richard", "id" : 65},
            {"name" : "Carl", "id" : 66},
            {"name" : "Leslie", "id" : 67},
            {"name" : "Jordan", "id" : 68},
            {"name" : "Matt", "id" : 69},
            {"name" : "Steve", "id" : 70},
            {"name" : "Isaac", "id" : 71},
            {"name" : "Joe", "id" : 72},
            {"name" : "Sam", "id" : 73},
            {"name" : "Kelly", "id" : 74},
            {"name" : "Bob", "id" : 75},
            {"name" : "Raj", "id" : 76},
            {"name" : "Walter", "id" : 77},
            {"name" : "Jason", "id" : 78},
            {"name" : "Sarah", "id" : 79},
            {"name" : "Steph", "id" : 80},
            {"name" : "Peter", "id" : 131}
        ]

    else:
        #abort(404)
        posts = []

    return render_template_string(posts_template, posts=posts)

posts_template = """

<head>
    {% block head %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://api.atmosonline.com/rest/namespace/infinitescroll/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js?uid=da8dd05dea2a4ee78ecd636db084bf47%2FA059402892dfadf9552c&expires=1403203192&signature=UciaR6fu6KdQd4ug9X608FXhqSA%3D"></script>

    {% endblock %}
</head>

{% block content %}
<div class="content">
    {% for post in posts %}

        {% if loop.first %}
        <div class="post">
            first: {{ post.name }}<br>
        </div>
        {% elif loop.last %}
        <div class="post">
            last: {{ post.name }}<br><br>
        </div>
            <a id= "pager" href="/posts/?token={{ posts[loop.index0]['id'] }}">Older &rarr;</a>

        {% else %}
        <div class="post">
            {{ post.name }}<br>
        </div>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}

<script>

    $('#pager').infinitescroll(
    {

        loading: {
            finished: undefined,
            finishedMsg: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>",
            img: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlh3AATAPQeAPDy+MnQ6LW/4N3h8MzT6rjC4sTM5r/I5NHX7N7j8c7U6tvg8OLl8uXo9Ojr9b3G5MfP6Ovu9tPZ7PT1+vX2+tbb7vf4+8/W69jd7rC73vn5/O/x+K243ai02////wAAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh+QQECgD/ACwAAAAA3AATAAAF/6AnjmRpnmiqrmzrvnAsz3Rt33iu73zv/8CgcEj0BAScpHLJbDqf0Kh0Sq1ar9isdioItAKGw+MAKYMFhbF63CW438f0mg1R2O8EuXj/aOPtaHx7fn96goR4hmuId4qDdX95c4+RBIGCB4yAjpmQhZN0YGYGXitdZBIVGAsLoq4BBKQDswm1CQRkcG6ytrYKubq8vbfAcMK9v7q7EMO1ycrHvsW6zcTKsczNz8HZw9vG3cjTsMIYqQkCLBwHCgsMDQ4RDAYIqfYSFxDxEfz88/X38Onr16+Bp4ADCco7eC8hQYMAEe57yNCew4IVBU7EGNDiRn8Z831cGLHhSIgdFf9chIeBg7oA7gjaWUWTVQAGE3LqBDCTlc9WOHfm7PkTqNCh54rePDqB6M+lR536hCpUqs2gVZM+xbrTqtGoWqdy1emValeXKzggYBBB5y1acFNZmEvXAoN2cGfJrTv3bl69Ffj2xZt3L1+/fw3XRVw4sGDGcR0fJhxZsF3KtBTThZxZ8mLMgC3fRatCbYMNFCzwLEqLgE4NsDWs/tvqdezZf13Hvk2A9Szdu2X3pg18N+68xXn7rh1c+PLksI/Dhe6cuO3ow3NfV92bdArTqC2Ebd3A8vjf5QWfH6Bg7Nz17c2fj69+fnq+8N2Lty+fuP78/eV2X13neIcCeBRwxorbZrA1ANoCDGrgoG8RTshahQ9iSKEEzUmYIYfNWViUhheCGJyIP5E4oom7WWjgCeBFAJNv1DVV01MAdJhhjdkplWNzO/5oXI846njjVEIqR2OS2B1pE5PVscajkxhMycqLJghQSwT40PgfAl4GqNSXYdZXJn5gSkmmmmJu1aZYb14V51do+pTOCmA40AqVCIhG5IJ9PvYnhIFOxmdqhpaI6GeHCtpooisuutmg+Eg62KOMKuqoTaXgicQWoIYq6qiklmoqFV0UoeqqrLbq6quwxirrrLTWauutJ4QAACH5BAUKABwALAcABADOAAsAAAX/IPd0D2dyRCoUp/k8gpHOKtseR9yiSmGbuBykler9XLAhkbDavXTL5k2oqFqNOxzUZPU5YYZd1XsD72rZpBjbeh52mSNnMSC8lwblKZGwi+0QfIJ8CncnCoCDgoVnBHmKfByGJimPkIwtiAeBkH6ZHJaKmCeVnKKTHIihg5KNq4uoqmEtcRUtEREMBggtEr4QDrjCuRC8h7/BwxENeicSF8DKy82pyNLMOxzWygzFmdvD2L3P0dze4+Xh1Arkyepi7dfFvvTtLQkZBC0T/FX3CRgCMOBHsJ+EHYQY7OinAGECgQsB+Lu3AOK+CewcWjwxQeJBihtNGHSoQOE+iQ3//4XkwBBhRZMcUS6YSXOAwIL8PGqEaSJCiYt9SNoCmnJPAgUVLChdaoFBURN8MAzl2PQphwQLfDFd6lTowglHve6rKpbjhK7/pG5VinZP1qkiz1rl4+tr2LRwWU64cFEihwEtZgbgR1UiHaMVvxpOSwBA37kzGz9e8G+B5MIEKLutOGEsAH2ATQwYfTmuX8aETWdGPZmiZcccNSzeTCA1Sw0bdiitC7LBWgu8jQr8HRzqgpK6gX88QbrB14z/kF+ELpwB8eVQj/JkqdylAudji/+ts3039vEEfK8Vz2dlvxZKG0CmbkKDBvllRd6fCzDvBLKBDSCeffhRJEFebFk1k/Mv9jVIoIJZSeBggwUaNeB+Qk34IE0cXlihcfRxkOAJFFhwGmKlmWDiakZhUJtnLBpnWWcnKaAZcxI0piFGGLBm1mc90kajSCveeBVWKeYEoU2wqeaQi0PetoE+rr14EpVC7oAbAUHqhYExbn2XHHsVqbcVew9tx8+XJKk5AZsqqdlddGpqAKdbAYBn1pcczmSTdWvdmZ17c1b3FZ99vnTdCRFM8OEcAhLwm1NdXnWcBBSMRWmfkWZqVlsmLIiAp/o1gGV2vpS4lalGYsUOqXrddcKCmK61aZ8SjEpUpVFVoCpTj4r661Km7kBHjrDyc1RAIQAAIfkEBQoAGwAsBwAEAM4ACwAABf/gtmUCd4goQQgFKj6PYKi0yrrbc8i4ohQt12EHcal+MNSQiCP8gigdz7iCioaCIvUmZLp8QBzW0EN2vSlCuDtFKaq4RyHzQLEKZNdiQDhRDVooCwkbfm59EAmKi4SGIm+AjIsKjhsqB4mSjT2IOIOUnICeCaB/mZKFNTSRmqVpmJqklSqskq6PfYYCDwYHDC4REQwGCBLGxxIQDsHMwhAIX8bKzcENgSLGF9PU1j3Sy9zX2NrgzQziChLk1BHWxcjf7N046tvN82715czn9Pryz6Ilc4ACj4EBOCZM8KEnAYYADBRKnACAYUMFv1wotIhCEcaJCisqwJFgAUSQGyX/kCSVUUTIdKMwJlyo0oXHlhskwrTJciZHEXsgaqS4s6PJiCAr1uzYU8kBBSgnWFqpoMJMUjGtDmUwkmfVmVypakWhEKvXsS4nhLW5wNjVroJIoc05wSzTr0PtiigpYe4EC2vj4iWrFu5euWIMRBhacaVJhYQBEFjA9jHjyQ0xEABwGceGAZYjY0YBOrRLCxUp29QM+bRkx5s7ZyYgVbTqwwti2ybJ+vLtDYpycyZbYOlptxdx0kV+V7lC5iJAyyRrwYKxAdiz82ng0/jnAdMJFz0cPi104Ec1Vj9/M6F173vKL/feXv156dw11tlqeMMnv4V5Ap53GmjQQH97nFfg+IFiucfgRX5Z8KAgbUlQ4IULIlghhhdOSB6AgX0IVn8eReghen3NRIBsRgnH4l4LuEidZBjwRpt6NM5WGwoW0KSjCwX6yJSMab2GwwAPDXfaBCtWpluRTQqC5JM5oUZAjUNS+VeOLWpJEQ7VYQANW0INJSZVDFSnZphjSikfmzE5N4EEbQI1QJmnWXCmHulRp2edwDXF43txukenJwvI9xyg9Q26Z3MzGUcBYFEChZh6DVTq34AU8Iflh51Sd+CnKFYQ6mmZkhqfBKfSxZWqA9DZanWjxmhrWwi0qtCrt/43K6WqVjjpmhIqgEGvculaGKklKstAACEAACH5BAUKABwALAcABADOAAsAAAX/ICdyQmaMYyAUqPgIBiHPxNpy79kqRXH8wAPsRmDdXpAWgWdEIYm2llCHqjVHU+jjJkwqBTecwItShMXkEfNWSh8e1NGAcLgpDGlRgk7EJ/6Ae3VKfoF/fDuFhohVeDeCfXkcCQqDVQcQhn+VNDOYmpSWaoqBlUSfmowjEA+iEAEGDRGztAwGCDcXEA60tXEiCrq8vREMEBLIyRLCxMWSHMzExnbRvQ2Sy7vN0zvVtNfU2tLY3rPgLdnDvca4VQS/Cpk3ABwSLQkYAQwT/P309vcI7OvXr94jBQMJ/nskkGA/BQBRLNDncAIAiDcG6LsxAWOLiQzmeURBKWSLCQbv/1F0eDGinJUKR47YY1IEgQASKk7Yc7ACRwZm7mHweRJoz59BJUogisKCUaFMR0x4SlJBVBFTk8pZivTR0K73rN5wqlXEAq5Fy3IYgHbEzQ0nLy4QSoCjXLoom96VOJEeCosK5n4kkFfqXjl94wa+l1gvAcGICbewAOAxY8l/Ky/QhAGz4cUkGxu2HNozhwMGBnCUqUdBg9UuW9eUynqSwLHIBujePef1ZGQZXcM+OFuEBeBhi3OYgLyqcuaxbT9vLkf4SeqyWxSQpKGB2gQpm1KdWbu72rPRzR9Ne2Nu9Kzr/1Jqj0yD/fvqP4aXOt5sW/5qsXXVcv1Nsp8IBUAmgswGF3llGgeU1YVXXKTN1FlhWFXW3gIE+DVChApysACHHo7Q4A35lLichh+ROBmLKAzgYmYEYDAhCgxKGOOMn4WR4kkDaoBBOxJtdNKQxFmg5JIWIBnQc07GaORfUY4AEkdV6jHlCEISSZ5yTXpp1pbGZbkWmcuZmQCaE6iJ0FhjMaDjTMsgZaNEHFRAQVp3bqXnZED1qYcECOz5V6BhSWCoVJQIKuKQi2KFKEkEFAqoAo7uYSmO3jk61wUUMKmknJ4SGimBmAa0qVQBhAAAIfkEBQoAGwAsBwAEAM4ACwAABf/gJm5FmRlEqhJC+bywgK5pO4rHI0D3pii22+Mg6/0Ej96weCMAk7cDkXf7lZTTnrMl7eaYoy10JN0ZFdco0XAuvKI6qkgVFJXYNwjkIBcNBgR8TQoGfRsJCRuCYYQQiI+ICosiCoGOkIiKfSl8mJkHZ4U9kZMbKaI3pKGXmJKrngmug4WwkhA0lrCBWgYFCCMQFwoQDRHGxwwGCBLMzRLEx8iGzMMO0cYNeCMKzBDW19lnF9DXDIY/48Xg093f0Q3s1dcR8OLe8+Y91OTv5wrj7o7B+7VNQqABIoRVCMBggsOHE36kSoCBIcSH3EbFangxogJYFi8CkJhqQciLJEf/LDDJEeJIBT0GsOwYUYJGBS0fjpQAMidGmyVP6sx4Y6VQhzs9VUwkwqaCCh0tmKoFtSMDmBOf9phg4SrVrROuasRQAaxXpVUhdsU6IsECZlvX3kwLUWzRt0BHOLTbNlbZG3vZinArge5Dvn7wbqtQkSYAAgtKmnSsYKVKo2AfW048uaPmG386i4Q8EQMBAIAnfB7xBxBqvapJ9zX9WgRS2YMpnvYMGdPK3aMjt/3dUcNI4blpj7iwkMFWDXDvSmgAlijrt9RTR78+PS6z1uAJZIe93Q8g5zcsWCi/4Y+C8bah5zUv3vv89uft30QP23punGCx5954oBBwnwYaNCDY/wYrsYeggnM9B2Fpf8GG2CEUVWhbWAtGouEGDy7Y4IEJVrbSiXghqGKIo7z1IVcXIkKWWR361QOLWWnIhwERpLaaCCee5iMBGJQmJGyPFTnbkfHVZGRtIGrg5HALEJAZbu39BuUEUmq1JJQIPtZilY5hGeSWsSk52G9XqsmgljdIcABytq13HyIM6RcUA+r1qZ4EBF3WHWB29tBgAzRhEGhig8KmqKFv8SeCeo+mgsF7YFXa1qWSbkDpom/mqR1PmHCqJ3fwNRVXjC7S6CZhFVCQ2lWvZiirhQq42SACt25IK2hv8TprriUV1usGgeka7LFcNmCldMLi6qZMgFLgpw16Cipb7bC1knXsBiEAACH5BAUKABsALAcABADOAAsAAAX/4FZsJPkUmUGsLCEUTywXglFuSg7fW1xAvNWLF6sFFcPb42C8EZCj24EJdCp2yoegWsolS0Uu6fmamg8n8YYcLU2bXSiRaXMGvqV6/KAeJAh8VgZqCX+BexCFioWAYgqNi4qAR4ORhRuHY408jAeUhAmYYiuVlpiflqGZa5CWkzc5fKmbbhIpsAoQDRG8vQwQCBLCwxK6vb5qwhfGxxENahvCEA7NzskSy7vNzzzK09W/PNHF1NvX2dXcN8K55cfh69Luveol3vO8zwi4Yhj+AQwmCBw4IYclDAAJDlQggVOChAoLKkgFkSCAHDwWLKhIEOONARsDKryogFPIiAUb/95gJNIiw4wnI778GFPhzBKFOAq8qLJEhQpiNArjMcHCmlTCUDIouTKBhApELSxFWiGiVKY4E2CAekPgUphDu0742nRrVLJZnyrFSqKQ2ohoSYAMW6IoDpNJ4bLdILTnAj8KUF7UeENjAKuDyxIgOuGiOI0EBBMgLNew5AUrDTMGsFixwBIaNCQuAXJB57qNJ2OWm2Aj4skwCQCIyNkhhtMkdsIuodE0AN4LJDRgfLPtn5YDLdBlraAByuUbBgxQwICxMOnYpVOPej074OFdlfc0TqC62OIbcppHjV4o+LrieWhfT8JC/I/T6W8oCl29vQ0XjLdBaA3s1RcPBO7lFvpX8BVoG4O5jTXRQRDuJ6FDTzEWF1/BCZhgbyAKE9qICYLloQYOFtahVRsWYlZ4KQJHlwHS/IYaZ6sZd9tmu5HQm2xi1UaTbzxYwJk/wBF5g5EEYOBZeEfGZmNdFyFZmZIR4jikbLThlh5kUUVJGmRT7sekkziRWUIACABk3T4qCsedgO4xhgGcY7q5pHJ4klBBTQRJ0CeHcoYHHUh6wgfdn9uJdSdMiebGJ0zUPTcoS286FCkrZxnYoYYKWLkBowhQoBeaOlZAgVhLidrXqg2GiqpQpZ4apwSwRtjqrB3muoF9BboaXKmshlqWqsWiGt2wphJkQbAU5hoCACH5BAUKABsALAcABADOAAsAAAX/oGFw2WZuT5oZROsSQnGaKjRvilI893MItlNOJ5v5gDcFrHhKIWcEYu/xFEqNv6B1N62aclysF7fsZYe5aOx2yL5aAUGSaT1oTYMBwQ5VGCAJgYIJCnx1gIOBhXdwiIl7d0p2iYGQUAQBjoOFSQR/lIQHnZ+Ue6OagqYzSqSJi5eTpTxGcjcSChANEbu8DBAIEsHBChe5vL13G7fFuscRDcnKuM3H0La3EA7Oz8kKEsXazr7Cw9/Gztar5uHHvte47MjktznZ2w0G1+D3BgirAqJmJMAQgMGEgwgn5Ei0gKDBhBMALGRYEOJBb5QcWlQo4cbAihZz3GgIMqFEBSM1/4ZEOWPAgpIIJXYU+PIhRG8ja1qU6VHlzZknJNQ6UanCjQkWCIGSUGEjAwVLjc44+DTqUQtPPS5gejUrTa5TJ3g9sWCr1BNUWZI161StiQUDmLYdGfesibQ3XMq1OPYthrwuA2yU2LBs2cBHIypYQPPlYAKFD5cVvNPtW8eVGbdcQADATsiNO4cFAPkvHpedPzc8kUcPgNGgZ5RNDZG05reoE9s2vSEP79MEGiQGy1qP8LA4ZcdtsJE48ONoLTBtTV0B9LsTnPceoIDBDQvS7W7vfjVY3q3eZ4A339J4eaAmKqU/sV58HvJh2RcnIBsDUw0ABqhBA5aV5V9XUFGiHfVeAiWwoFgJJrIXRH1tEMiDFV4oHoAEGlaWhgIGSGBO2nFomYY3mKjVglidaNYJGJDkWW2xxTfbjCbVaOGNqoX2GloR8ZeTaECS9pthRGJH2g0b3Agbk6hNANtteHD2GJUucfajCQBy5OOTQ25ZgUPvaVVQmbKh9510/qQpwXx3SQdfk8tZJOd5b6JJFplT3ZnmmX3qd5l1eg5q00HrtUkUn0AKaiGjClSAgKLYZcgWXwocGRcCFGCKwSB6ceqphwmYRUFYT/1WKlOdUpipmxW0mlCqHjYkAaeoZlqrqZ4qd+upQKaapn/AmgAegZ8KUtYtFAQQAgAh+QQFCgAbACwHAAQAzgALAAAF/+C2PUcmiCiZGUTrEkKBis8jQEquKwU5HyXIbEPgyX7BYa5wTNmEMwWsSXsqFbEh8DYs9mrgGjdK6GkPY5GOeU6ryz7UFopSQEzygOGhJBjoIgMDBAcBM0V/CYqLCQqFOwobiYyKjn2TlI6GKC2YjJZknouaZAcQlJUHl6eooJwKooobqoewrJSEmyKdt59NhRKFMxLEEA4RyMkMEAjDEhfGycqAG8TQx9IRDRDE3d3R2ctD1RLg0ttKEnbY5wZD3+zJ6M7X2RHi9Oby7u/r9g38UFjTh2xZJBEBMDAboogAgwkQI07IMUORwocSJwCgWDFBAIwZOaJIsOBjRogKJP8wTODw5ESVHVtm3AhzpEeQElOuNDlTZ0ycEUWKWFASqEahGwYUPbnxoAgEdlYSqDBkgoUNClAlIHbSAoOsqCRQnQHxq1axVb06FWFxLIqyaze0Tft1JVqyE+pWXMD1pF6bYl3+HTqAWNW8cRUFzmih0ZAAB2oGKukSAAGGRHWJgLiR6AylBLpuHKKUMlMCngMpDSAa9QIUggZVVvDaJobLeC3XZpvgNgCmtPcuwP3WgmXSq4do0DC6o2/guzcseECtUoO0hmcsGKDgOt7ssBd07wqesAIGZC1YIBa7PQHvb1+SFo+++HrJSQfB33xfav3i5eX3Hnb4CTJgegEq8tH/YQEOcIJzbm2G2EoYRLgBXFpVmFYDcREV4HIcnmUhiGBRouEMJGJGzHIspqgdXxK0yCKHRNXoIX4uorCdTyjkyNtdPWrA4Up82EbAbzMRxxZRR54WXVLDIRmRcag5d2R6ugl3ZXzNhTecchpMhIGVAKAYpgJjjsSklBEd99maZoo535ZvdamjBEpusJyctg3h4X8XqodBMx0tiNeg/oGJaKGABpogS40KSqiaEgBqlQWLUtqoVQnytekEjzo0hHqhRorppOZt2p923M2AAV+oBtpAnnPNoB6HaU6mAAIU+IXmi3j2mtFXuUoHKwXpzVrsjcgGOauKEjQrwq157hitGq2NoWmjh7z6Wmxb0m5w66+2VRAuXN/yFUAIACH5BAUKABsALAcABADOAAsAAAX/4CZuRiaM45MZqBgIRbs9AqTcuFLE7VHLOh7KB5ERdjJaEaU4ClO/lgKWjKKcMiJQ8KgumcieVdQMD8cbBeuAkkC6LYLhOxoQ2PF5Ys9PKPBMen17f0CCg4VSh32JV4t8jSNqEIOEgJKPlkYBlJWRInKdiJdkmQlvKAsLBxdABA4RsbIMBggtEhcQsLKxDBC2TAS6vLENdJLDxMZAubu8vjIbzcQRtMzJz79S08oQEt/guNiyy7fcvMbh4OezdAvGrakLAQwyABsELQkY9BP+//ckyPDD4J9BfAMh1GsBoImMeQUN+lMgUJ9CiRMa5msxoB9Gh/o8GmxYMZXIgxtR/yQ46S/gQAURR0pDwYDfywoyLPip5AdnCwsMFPBU4BPFhKBDi444quCmDKZOfwZ9KEGpCKgcN1jdALSpPqIYsabS+nSqvqplvYqQYAeDPgwKwjaMtiDl0oaqUAyo+3TuWwUAMPpVCfee0cEjVBGQq2ABx7oTWmQk4FglZMGN9fGVDMCuiH2AOVOu/PmyxM630gwM0CCn6q8LjVJ8GXvpa5Uwn95OTC/nNxkda1/dLSK475IjCD6dHbK1ZOa4hXP9DXs5chJ00UpVm5xo2qRpoxptwF2E4/IbJpB/SDz9+q9b1aNfQH08+p4a8uvX8B53fLP+ycAfemjsRUBgp1H20K+BghHgVgt1GXZXZpZ5lt4ECjxYR4ScUWiShEtZqBiIInRGWnERNnjiBglw+JyGnxUmGowsyiiZg189lNtPGACjV2+S9UjbU0JWF6SPvEk3QZEqsZYTk3UAaRSUnznJI5LmESCdBVSyaOWUWLK4I5gDUYVeV1T9l+FZClCAUVA09uSmRHBCKAECFEhW51ht6rnmWBXkaR+NjuHpJ40D3DmnQXt2F+ihZxlqVKOfQRACACH5BAUKABwALAcABADOAAsAAAX/ICdyUCkUo/g8mUG8MCGkKgspeC6j6XEIEBpBUeCNfECaglBcOVfJFK7YQwZHQ6JRZBUqTrSuVEuD3nI45pYjFuWKvjjSkCoRaBUMWxkwBGgJCXspQ36Bh4EEB0oKhoiBgyNLjo8Ki4QElIiWfJqHnISNEI+Ql5J9o6SgkqKkgqYihamPkW6oNBgSfiMMDQkGCBLCwxIQDhHIyQwQCGMKxsnKVyPCF9DREQ3MxMPX0cu4wt7J2uHWx9jlKd3o39MiuefYEcvNkuLt5O8c1ePI2tyELXGQwoGDAQf+iEC2xByDCRAjTlAgIUWCBRgCPJQ4AQBFXAs0coT40WLIjRxL/47AcHLkxIomRXL0CHPERZkpa4q4iVKiyp0tR/7kwHMkTUBBJR5dOCEBAVcKKtCAyOHpowXCpk7goABqBZdcvWploACpBKkpIJI1q5OD2rIWE0R1uTZu1LFwbWL9OlKuWb4c6+o9i3dEgw0RCGDUG9KlRw56gDY2qmCByZBaASi+TACA0TucAaTteCcy0ZuOK3N2vJlx58+LRQyY3Xm0ZsgjZg+oPQLi7dUcNXi0LOJw1pgNtB7XG6CBy+U75SYfPTSQAgZTNUDnQHt67wnbZyvwLgKiMN3oCZB3C76tdewpLFgIP2C88rbi4Y+QT3+8S5USMICZXWj1pkEDeUU3lOYGB3alSoEiMIjgX4WlgNF2EibIwQIXauWXSRg2SAOHIU5IIIMoZkhhWiJaiFVbKo6AQEgQXrTAazO1JhkBrBG3Y2Y6EsUhaGn95hprSN0oWpFE7rhkeaQBchGOEWnwEmc0uKWZj0LeuNV3W4Y2lZHFlQCSRjTIl8uZ+kG5HU/3sRlnTG2ytyadytnD3HrmuRcSn+0h1dycexIK1KCjYaCnjCCVqOFFJTZ5GkUUjESWaUIKU2lgCmAKKQIUjHapXRKE+t2og1VgankNYnohqKJ2CmKplso6GKz7WYCgqxeuyoF8u9IQAgA7",
            msg: null,
            msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>",
            selector: null,
            speed: 'slow',
            start: undefined
        },
        state: {
            isDuringAjax: false,
            isInvalidPage: false,
            isDestroyed: false,
            isDone: false, // For when it goes all the way through the archive.
            isPaused: false,
            currPage: 1
        },
        debug: true,
        behavior: undefined,
        binder: $(window), // used to cache the selector for the element that will be scrolling
        nextSelector: "a:first",
        navSelector: "#pager",
        contentSelector: "div.content", // rename to pageFragment
        extraScrollPx: 150,
        itemSelector: "div.content div.post",
        animate: false,
        pathParse: undefined,
        dataType: 'html',
        appendCallback: true,
        bufferPx: 40,
        errorCallback: function () { },
        infid: 0, //Instance ID
        pixelsFromNavToBottom: undefined,
        path: undefined, // Can either be an array of URL parts (e.g. ["/page/", "/"]) or a function that accepts the page number and returns a URL
        prefill: false, // When the document is smaller than the window, load data until the document is larger or links are exhausted
        maxPage:undefined // to manually control maximum page (when maxPage is undefined, maximum page limitation is not work)
    });

    </script>

"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: It seems to be working as intended for me, using your exact code. I checked in Chromium.

Comment: Really?  How many times do you get new pages?  And can you try in Firefox by chance?

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome and it doesn't work.  It only paginates once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem.  Turns out that the infinite scroll plugin tries to guess the pagination using some built-in heuristics.

I ended up having to write a custom function for the `pathParse` option to handle my URL which uses tokens instead of page numbers.